# ValueError: Either a title or a pageid must be specified

Tags: python, tkinter, wikipedia-api

The code displayed below is giving me a ValueError, explaining I need a title or pagid specified. I have checked the code over and over and do not see a problem. Please let me know if you have any idea what I am doing wrong.

This code is meant to give me information about most key words I enter. If I want Jeff Bezos, information will be printed to the console.

```
# Imports
import wikipedia
from tkinter import *
import time

# Code
def Application():
    # Definitions
    def Research():
        # Defines Entry
        Result = wikipedia.summary(Term)

        print(Result)

    # Window Specifications
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('900x700')
    root.title('Wikipedia Research')

    # Window Contents
    Title = Label(root, text = 'Wikipedia Research Tool', font = ('Arial', 25)).place(y = 10, x = 250)

    Directions = Label(root, text = 'Enter a Term Below', font = ('Arial, 15')).place(y = 210, x = 345)

    Term = Entry(root, font = ('Arial, 15')).place(y = 250, x = 325)

    Run = Button(root, font = ('Arial, 15'), text = 'Go', command = Research).place(y = 300, x = 415)

    # Mainloop
    root.mainloop()

# Run Application
Application()
```

Comment: @PranavHosangadi gotcha, I agree that posting the full stacktrace would have been really helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing `Term` to `wikipedia.summary()`. The error is coming from when `summary()` creates a `page` ([code](https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia/blob/master/wikipedia/wikipedia.py#L231)). This error happens when there is no valid title or page ID being passed to the `page` ([code](https://mediawikiapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/mediawikiapi/mediawikiapi.html)). This is happening in your case because you're passing `Term` straight to `summary()`, without first converting it to a string. Additionally, `Term` is a `NoneType` object, because you're actually setting it to the result of `place()`. You have to store `Term` when you create the `Entry()`, and then apply the `place` operation to it, in order to be able to keep a reference to it (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name) for why):

```
Term = Entry(root, font = ('Arial, 15'))
Term.place(y = 250, x = 325)
```

Then, you can get the text value via:

```
Result = wikipedia.summary(Term.get())
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name) problem :D

Comment: Thanks so much! I honestly forgot about the '.get()' function!

Comment: @brrrrrrrt no problem, and also keep in mind that `get()` won't work without first making sure `Term` is set to the result of `Entry()` rather than `place()`.

Comment: @RandomDavis I do not really understand that, can you elaborate?

Comment: `Term.get()` is the fix, but it won't work unless you also separate `Term = Entry(...).place(...)` into two separate lines, like I showed in my example. See the link in @TheLizzard's comment for an explanation of why.